# Mysql:enter text, which type to use?

Tags: java, mysql

I would like to insert into a field in a mysql table that allows a variable to input text without limitation the maximum length.
Which type should I use?
Usually I used "varchar" but does not go well, because many times the texts are too long!

Comment: Every data type has a limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **LONGTEXT**    its capacity is upto 4GB.

Comment: but the syntax would be the following: 'content' LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL

Comment: @user3190716 Check this url it have all the detail you want [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html]

Answer (score 0):

```
TINYTEXT
TEXT
MEDIUMTEXT
LONGTEXT
```

Comment: Could you explain how this helps?

Answer (score 0):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html

> A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of
>   data. The four BLOB types are TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, and
>   LONGBLOB. These differ only in the maximum length of the values they
>   can hold. The four TEXT types are TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and
>   LONGTEXT. These correspond to the four BLOB types and have the same
>   maximum lengths and storage requirements. See Section 11.6, “Data Type
>   Storage Requirements”.

You should then use one of the text types: TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

*> input text without limitation...*

You should never do that if yo want avoid the errors. Try to substring text, like:

```
int yourLimit = 4096; // Maximum length of TINYTEXT or TEXT or MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT (will find the length easy in MySQL documentation)

someText = someText.substring(0, yourLimit);
```